# Good starting point for NLP sentence classification on limited computational resources?

Tags: classification, natural-language

I am designing a project where I plan to train a supervised ML model to classify English sentences of 10-30 words long into one of 8 or 9 categories by what kind of meaning it conveys. I have a good PC (i7 8core, 16G RAM, 1050 Ti) but it does not hold up against large models like BERT. I am wondering what are the best LSTM's or encoders specifically designed for this kind of training that can achieve relatively good performance using limited hardware.

Comment: Very few PCs hold up against large models like BERT, period. You could try a smaller version of the model from here — https://github.com/google-research/bert — maybe huggingface has one of those built-in already. However, in my experience, I've always just had to spin up an AWS instance or something similar to train BERT in a reasonable amount of time (hours instead of days).

Comment: Have you tried [Google  Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) notebooks?